# Require multiple rails sites from script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to access the databases used by two completely separate Rails sites from an external Ruby script. I know that I can require the environment of a Rails app, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "/path/to/rails/app/config/environment"
```

I can then use all the models defined in the Rails app to read and write data and it will use the database settings defined for the site.

But now I want to do this for two sites at the same time, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "/path/to/first/rails/app/config/environment"
require "/path/to/second/rails/app/config/environment"
```

Clearly, that will not work as the application can not be initialised twice. Is there any way to avoid the collision?

Comment: Yes, you can think of doing this by using Rake tasks...

Comment: I should add that I want to do this in a long-running background process so I can't load the Rails environments every time. My other thought would be make the database calls directly without using Rails at all. However, if I could use the configuration I avoid duplicate the configuration and also get the benefit of using the validations already present in the two Rails apps.

Comment: Well, then it seems, you can use API calls.. I think it is fairly possible.. Using background jobs.

Comment: Wrap your models of the two apps in separate Rails Engines (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) - then you can write one app which requires both gems. In this app you can create the rake task.